# Embedded Google Map can't get current location in WebView

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, android-maps, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-places

I followed this tutorial: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/03/embed-google-map-in-webview.html

I'm trying to just use the Google Map in the WebView, but it can't get my current location. I've enabled JavaScript on the WebView. What else do I have to enable?

Does anyone know why that might be? Shouldn't it prompt me to use my current location?

Note that I am not interested in using a MapView as an alternative whatsoever. I'm trying to find out what I need to set on the WebView or maybe on the device's location services?

Comment: Seriously? Nobody else has run into this problem??

Comment: Hi Darren I ran into the same problem and @Kumait's solution has fixed it. You should try the same solution and if it works, accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should permit the web view to access your location by overriding the method `onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt` like this:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

On API 5.x and below, you will need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

But to allow permissions for geolocation on API 6.0+, you have to [request the permission at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

[image: Request location permission]

To do this, use

```
private String mGeolocationOrigin;
private GeolocationPermissions.Callback mGeolocationCallback;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // other setup

    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
}

private WebChromeClient mWebChromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
                                                   GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        // Geolocation permissions coming from this app's Manifest will only be valid for devices with API_VERSION < 23.
        // On API 23 and above, we must check for permission, and possibly ask for it.
        final String permission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M ||
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // we're on SDK < 23 OR user has already granted permission
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        } else {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, permission)) {
                // user has denied this permission before and selected [/] DON'T ASK ME AGAIN
                // TODO Best Practice: show an AlertDialog explaining why the user could allow this permission, then ask again
            } else {
                // ask the user for permissions
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] {permission}, RP_ACCESS_LOCATION);
                mGeolocationOrigin = origin;
                mGeolocationCallback = callback;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and receive the result:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RP_ACCESS_LOCATION:
            boolean allow = false;
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // user has allowed these permissions
                allow = true;
            }
            if (mGeolocationCallback != null) {
                mGeolocationCallback.invoke(mGeolocationOrigin, allow, false);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

in your activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can try GreenDroid with Google Maps.

Checkt it out: https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to enable `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `android.permission.INTERNET`,

Create a `LocationManager` instance and `LocationListener` instance

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();  
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);
```

and add `onLocationChanged(Location loc)` method that inside of it have your `loc` generate the longitude and latitude (`String long = loc.getLongitude(); String lat = loc.getLatitude();`)

and now use `long, lat` to generate your `mapPath` string and continue to generate the `WebView`

You can use this for ref: http://www.rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/01/get-current-location-coordinates-city.html

Comment: I don't think I made this clear, but the link that I provided is expected to work out of the box. For my specific problem, I'm creating a mobile website that uses the JavaScript Google Maps API, so I don't have any control over the native WebView.