# Get Current Location in WebView Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, webview

I have a link of my custom made map in Google which includes marker to several destinations , what i want is to get the `current Location` of user and show a marker or something on that location without disturbing my other markers in google map.

i have following Google map which i want to show in **webView**: `https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1Wm3cIfP77Z8av8wGOi7xzQvrVxY`

what modifications i should do in `URL` or android code to make it work?

my attempt: `https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/dir/Current+Location/viewer?mid=1qriRe112Bm54KPXEgtfeA6n2la8&z=5` **[FAILED]**

**Edited:**

`https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1qriRe112Bm54KPXEgtfeA6n2la8&z=5&saddr=Current+Location` **[FAILED]**

Comment: try this [google map loading webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486037/embedded-google-map-cant-get-current-location-in-webview)

Comment: given method doesn't work @RameshPrajapati

Comment: my question is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance of a WebView and load the `URL` of the Google Maps site. You can add parameters to the URL which allows you to use more functionality than is available using the Java-based [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/web/).

Below code snippet shows how to create instance of a WebView to display a mobile Google Maps [URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/#URL_Parameters) with parameters in an Android App. The main activity of your app should contain the following lines in its [`onCreate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) method.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      webView.loadUrl("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?
       ll=36.97,%20-122&lci=bike&z=13&t=p&size=500x500&sensor=true");
}
```