# how do i get my current location on my google maps webview app

Tags: android, webview, currentlocation

I want to make an app with WebView google maps, but I can't get my current location in WebView, how do I grant the the access so the app can get my current location. I already tried to grant my coarse and fine location on my android manifest but it won't work.

This is my code:

[image: my java code]

My XML:

[image: my xml]

[image: android manifest]

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow ! Try to avoid code as image. Prefer copy/paste, it's better to us to read and try ourself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embedded Google Map can't get current location in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486037/embedded-google-map-cant-get-current-location-in-webview)